# Degree of the field extension $\bar{k}(Z_f) /\bar{k}(x)$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, arithmetic-geometry, function-fields

I came across an argument on the lecture notes. It does not have a proof of the fact and I want to understand the argument.

Let $k$ be a field, $f(x,y) \in \bar{k}[x,y]$. Define $Z_f := \{(a,b) \in \bar{k} \times \bar{k} | f(a,b)=0\}$, $C_f :=\bar{k}[x,y]/(f)$ and $\bar{k}(Z_f)=Frac(C_f)$.

*Then, $\bar{k}(Z_f)/\bar{k}(x)$ is a field extension of degree $f$.*

I could not do anything much. I have few ideas like writing $f$ as $f(x,y)=a_n(x)y^n+\dots+a_1(x)y+a_0(x) \in \bar{k}[x][y]$.
I do not know how to write the elements of $Frac(C_f)$ in a "nice way".

I mean better than writing this :$Frac(C_f)=\cfrac{p(x,y)+(f)}{q(x,y)+(f)}$.

So, I appreciate if you could enlighten me. How is that a field extension, what are the elements of it and what is the degree of $f$? I think the degree is the degree with respect to $y$ but not sure whether it is total degree or not.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to clarify some things. Which degree of $f$ do you mean? I guess it is the degree w.r.t $y$ and you are assuming that this is non-zero?

Comment: If $\deg_y f=0$, then the obvious map $k[x] \to k[x,y]/f$ is not generically finite, hence the assertion is false.

Comment: I do not  know the type of degree because it is not mentioned on the notes. I assumed that it is with respect to $y$ so it looks like the degree is the total degree then.

Comment: You just contradicted yourself...It is either the degree w.r.t $y$ or the total degree...

Comment: How did I contradict myself exactly? I already mentioned it above that some information is missing. Your comment is not helpful at all.